# Thymeleaf не видит поля объекта

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Вставлял все нужные зависимости, инжектил поля через Alt+Enter, с параметром xmlns:th повозился, но ничего не помогло. Может что-то упустил. Вожусь с этим уже 2 день.
В pom.xml стоят эти зависимости:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring5 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Сущность в БД:

```
package com.example.model;


import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.Date;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "purchase_info")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ID_SEQ", sequenceName = "PURCHASE_INFO_SEQ")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PurchaseInfo extends IdIdentity {

@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String fullName;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Integer age;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "purchase_id", nullable = false, insertable = false)
private Purchase purchase;

@Column
private Integer count;

@Column
private Long amount;

@Column(updatable = false)
@CreationTimestamp
private Date purchaseDate;

public PurchaseInfo(){

}
```

Контроллер:

```
package com.example.controller;

import com.example.model.PurchaseInfo;
import com.example.service.PurchaseInfoService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/purchaseInfo")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PurchaseInfoController {
private final PurchaseInfoService service;

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String getAll(Model model){
    List<PurchaseInfo> purchaseInfoList = service.getAll();
    model.addAttribute("purchaseInfoList", purchaseInfoList);

    return "index";
}
```

Html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PurchaseInfo Manager</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <h1>Purchase List</h1>
    <a href="/new">Create new purchase</a>
    <br>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>fullName</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>purchase_id</th>
            <th>count</th>
            <th>amount</th>
            <th>date</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!--/*@thymesVar id="purchaseInfoList" type="com.example.controller.PurchaseInfoController"*/-->
            <tr th:each="purchase : ${purchaseInfoList}">
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="id" type="java.lang.Long"*/-->
                <th th:text="*{purchase.id}"></th>
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="name" type="java.lang.String"*/-->
                <th th:text="${purchase.name}"></th>
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="fullName" type="java.lang.String"*/-->
                <th th:text="${purchase.fullName}"></th>
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="age" type="java.lang.Integer"*/-->
                <th th:text="${purchase.age}"></th>
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="purchase" type="java.lang.Integer"*/-->
                <th th:text="${purchase.purchase}"></th>
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="count" type="java.lang.Integer"*/-->
                <th th:text="${purchase.count}"></th>
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="amount" type="java.lang.Long"*/-->
                <th th:text="${purchase.amount}"></th>
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="date" type="java.util.Date"*/-->
                <th th:text="${purchase.date}"></th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для начала поменяйте RestController На Controller

Comment: @Serodv, как ни странно, после смены аннотации, IDE теперь высвечивает ошибки в index.html, и это хорошо! Но почему так?  Связано ли это как-то с перехватчиками, например, в SecurityConfig?

Comment: Разница огромная. В двух словах, Controller используется для монолитного веб-приложения, а RestController - для веб сервиса (в таком случае html существует независимо от бэкенда). Поэтому IDE пыталась связать объекты из шаблона с java-кодом, и у неё это не получалось.

Comment: @Serodv, гугление, на разницу между этими аннотациями, выдавало только то, что они отличаются краткостью написания(RestController = Controller + ResponseController). Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смена аннотации с @RestController на @Controller помогла, как и сказал @Serodv.
Также, следует удалить этот атрибут в теге : xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"

Answer (score 0):

У меня была проблема из-за того что я возвращал

```
@GetMapping("/registered")
    public String toRegisteredUserPage() {
        return "registered.html";
    }
```

вместо

```
@GetMapping("/registered")
    public String toRegisteredUserPage() {
        return "registered";
    }
```

еще можно попробовать добавить конфигурацию вручную

```
@Bean
    public ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        /*resolver.setPrefix("static/client");*/
        // For Spring Boot
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        return resolver;
    }
```